Potential of Monolayer Graphene as a High-Precision Cutting Material
"I am exploring the use of monolayer graphene as a cutting material for high-precision applications. We know that graphene has exceptional mechanical properties, such as high strength and stiffness, in addition to its extremely thin atomic thickness. I would like to discuss the advantages and challenges of using graphene for cutting at nanometer scales. Does anyone have experience or can share insights into its cutting properties, durability, and potential industrial applications?"
